# How to Combine SKTextures

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm looking for a way to combine an SKTexture on top of another SKTexture, similar in appearance to how a textured SKSpritenode would look when adding another textured SKSPritenode as a child. I need it to be a single SKTexture as an end-product please.

Comment: why won't two sprites suffice? you can use textureFromNode (or similar name), it's in the sk class reference

Comment: @LearnCocos2D - technically speaking, isn't it possible to overlay a number of nodes with alpha property texture to create a combination effect? Or did I just have a brain fart...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short of it is that you can't do it. A SKSpriteNode can only ever take one SKTexture. The only way to do this within the SpriteKit framework is to add children on top of the parent node.

Another way is to use a series of images and combine them before adding the final product as a texture to your sprite node.

```
CGSize mergedSize = CGSizeMake(maxWidth, maxHeight); // <- use the largest width and height for your images if they are different sizes
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(mergedSize, NO, 0.0f);
[textureImage1 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, maxWidth, textureImage1.size.height)];
[textureImage2 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 75, textureImage2.size.height)];
// ... add any additional images ...
UIImage *mergedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

self.texture = [SKTexture textureWithImage:mergedImage];
```

Make sure you have your SKSpriteNode size property set to (maxWidth, maxHeight) so nothing gets clipped.